# Corda contract verification called during CollectSignatureFlow and FinalityFlow

Tags: corda

As per corda documentaion and my understanding contract verification called at time of transactionBuilder. For R&D I put logger on contract verification function. One thing observed that contract verification called at time of transactionBuilder also in collectSignature and in finalityflow also.

In collectSignatureFlow called 3 times and Finality flow also called 3 times.

Current setup have 2 nodes one notary in non-validating mode.

My question is that in collectSignatureFlow verify called on diffrent nodes and if yes does notary called verify function too. Same question is with finality flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CollectSignaturesFlow`, called by the node gathering the signatures, calls `verify`. `SignTransactionFlow`, the responder flow called by the nodes adding their signatures, also calls `verify` before signing.

`FinalityFlow` calls `verify`. `NotaryServiceFlow`, the flow run by the notary in response to `FinalityFlow`, should call `verify` if the notary is validating (in fact, this is the definition of a validating notary). And finally, `ReceiveTransactionFlow`, the flow run by the transaction's participants in response to `FinalityFlow`, calls `verify` before storing the transaction.